# WCF Metadata reading exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service configured like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding allowCookies="true" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I'm trying to implement a client without contract and service reference to call methods by name, so far I'm trying to download the metadata using the code like this:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

// Set some quotas for the binding.
var readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
readerQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas;

var mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(binding);
var metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata(new EndpointAddress(wsdl));
```

The problem is no matter what url  use:

- http://mywcfserviceurl.com/Directory.svc?wsdl
- http://mywcfserviceurl.com/Directory.svc
- http://mywcfserviceurl.com/

Nothing works, the first two URLs throw an error stating that `The message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher`, the third one throws an error with code 405. The WCF service works properly and using WCF test client supplied with visual studio I can easily access it with the 2nd URL.